# How to increment div id with php for loop?

Tags: php

I have the following div. I would like to have `mydiv1`, `mydiv2` and `mydiv3`. Is this possible to do?

**Code:**

```
<?php for($i =1; $i <3; $i++):?>
    <div id="mydiv<?php $i?>" style="float:left">
<?php endfor;?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the inner for loop and you will get only 3 divs.

if you want to assign id's in div dynamically try this:

```
$somearray = array(
        'animal'=>'cat',
        'place'=>'earth',
        'food'=>'orange'
);
$i=1;
foreach ($somearray as $k=>$v){
    echo '<div id="div'.$i.'">'. $v .'<div>';
    $i++;
}
```

---

In your code you are getting 9 elements because what you are doing is first loop through `$somearray` elements which is 3 times and inside that loop you again loop for 3 times using variable `$i` so 3*3=9. and you are getting 9 divs.

Comment: bleh, second time in a row I've been beaten by a couple seconds :/

Answer (score 3):

Use `<?php echo $i; ?>` instead of `<?php $i?>`.

Comment: got it but i got 9 divs insted of 3 divs here is the full code      <?php for($i =1; $i<=3; $i++):?>
    <?php foreach($vfeat as $key=>$list):?>
     
    <div id="youtube<?php echo $i; ?>" style="float:left">
      
 <?php 
 echo $video->embed($list['v_url'], '415', '255');
 
 ?>
     </div>
     <?php endforeach;?>
     <?php endfor;?>

Comment: well <3   that are 3 loops, better do it with heredoc like i have shown you

Comment: @Daniel, I wouldn't say heredoc is beter, it is quite unreadable. Even double-quoted strings are easier to read.

Comment: @sagarmatha, you have a `for` loop, which contains `foreach` loop, that's why you got 9 divs (`$vfeat` probably consists of 3 elements).

Comment: @sagarmatha, if you need one `<div/>` for every element in `$vfeat`, remove `for` loop and use `$key` when printing div's ID. Something like `foreach ( $vfeat as $key => $list ) { echo "<div id='youtube{$key}'></div>"; }`

Comment: @binary  why should it be worse?

Comment: @Daniel, why would it be better? You say for some reason that it is better, I say that it is unreadable. Those are just our opinions, our preferences ;) To be honest, I can't recall any project where heredoc syntax would be used by myself or by my colleagues.

Comment: @sagarmatha, what exactly did not work? What results (or errors) did you get?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have 9 elements? Because you're generating nine elements.

```
$somearray = array(
        'animal'=>'cat',
        'place'=>'earth',
        'food'=>'orange'
);

foreach ($somearray as $k=>$v){
    for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++){
    echo '<div id="div'.$i.'">'. $v .'<div>';
    }
}
```

Let me elaborate:

The above code block is equal to this *set of codeblocks*.

where $somearray value = 'animal'=>'cat' do this:

```
for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++){
echo '<div id="div'.$i.'">'. $v .'<div>';
}
```

and

where $somearray value = 'place'=>'earth' do this:

```
for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++){
echo '<div id="div'.$i.'">'. $v .'<div>';
}
```

and

where $somearray value = 'food'=>'orange' do this:

```
for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++){
echo '<div id="div'.$i.'">'. $v .'<div>';
}
```

All because of this:

```
foreach ($somearray as $k=>$v){
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the inner `for` loop (3 x 3 = 9).  You simply need a counter that you increment on each iteration of the outer loop:

```
<?php

$somearray = array(
        'animal'=>'cat',
        'place'=>'earth',
        'food'=>'orange'
);

$counter = 1;
foreach ($somearray as $k=>$v){
    echo '<div id="div'.$counter .'">'. $v .'<div>';
    $counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
for($i =1; $i <3; $i++){
echo <<<CODE
<div id="mydiv$i" style="float:left;">
CODE;
}
?>
```

Comment: the problem in it's inside foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

You need to give like,

```
<div id="mydiv<?php echo $i;?>" style="float:left">
```

it will work.

Comment: please, format the code by selecting it and pressing `{}` icon in editor.