# how to increment div id in php?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to increment div id with php for loop ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016157/how-to-increment-div-id-with-php-for-loop)

I would like to have only 3 divs (div1, div2 and div3), but I am getting 9 divs. Why is this happening? I did ask this earlier but didn't solve my problem.

```
<?php

$somearray = array(
        'animal'=>'cat',
        'place'=>'earth',
        'food'=>'orange'
);

foreach ($somearray as $k=>$v){
    for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++){
    echo '<div id="div'.$i.'">'. $v .'<div>';
    }
}
```